# Multi-function conditional formatting cell range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I want to give a quick indication using coloured cells of the time likely to be taken to complete a task. So for example:

if cell B2 = 1 then fill cell range G2:H2 with light red
if cell B2 = 2 then fill cell range G2:J2 with light red
if cell B2 = 3 then fill cell range G2:L2 with light red

How might I achieve this?

Comment: So for each increment of cell B2 you want 2 more cells formatted as light red starting with G2:H2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select G2:H2 and use a CF formula rule of:

```
=$B$2=1
```

Select G2:J2 and use a CF formula rule of:

```
=$B$2=2
```

Select G2:L2 and use a CF formula rule of:

```
=$B$2=3
```

each with the formatting of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a dynamic formula and only **one** format setting you can select *all* the cells you want to format, then make a new conditional formatting rule using the formula:

```
=$B$2*2+COLUMN($G:$G)-COLUMN()>0
```

Which will affect 2 additional cells each time you increment `$B$2`.
I used your examples of `$B$2` and starting with `$G:$G` but you can change those if needed.

If you need multiple format settings this won't work.